# Vue.js запрос к spring. Spring security

Tags: vue.js

В общем, есть такая проблема. Хочу реализовать авторизацию с помощью spring security. Фронт написан на vue. Но возникает проблема, так как spring на localhost:8080, а vue на localhost:8081. При попытке открыть страницу lh:8081/page. У меня security не должен пускать на неё, а должен переадресовывать на lh:8081/login. Для этого при попытке открыть lh:8081/admin security перекидывает на lh:8080/login. Уже там я пытаюсь сделать redirect на lh:8081/login но возникает ошибка cors. 
Как можно это реализовать? И можно ли как то разворачивать spring и vue на одном сервере, но при этом, что бы приложения не с двумя модулями? (Не как здесь: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/04/spring-boot-vuejs/ )

Comment: Сумбурный вопрос. Переформулируйте его, внеся больше ясности... там есть кнопка "править"

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить аннотацию @CrossOrigin над контроллером

Можно указать в настройках webMVC глобально
Можно указать хедер Access-Control-Allow-Origin с нужным значением

Вот версия как включить этот в Spring Security конфигурации

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
            .allowedMethods("*");
}
```

Также вот гайд по этой теме:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/